# Solve $\rvert z-2 \rvert=(z^*)^2-1$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

$z^*$ is the conjugate of $z$

$$z=a+ib \qquad a,b \in \mathbb{R}$$

$$\sqrt{(a-2)^2+b^2}=a^2-2ab \ i-b^2-1$$

$$\sqrt{(a-2)^2+b^2} \in \mathbb{R}$$

So, $a=0$ XOR $b=0$

if $b=0$:
$$\sqrt{(a-2)^2}=a^2-1$$
$$a-2=a^2-1$$
$$a^2-a+1=0$$
$$a \notin \mathbb{R}$$

If $a=0$
$$\sqrt{b^2+4}=-(b^2+1)$$
$$b \notin \mathbb{R}$$

In my opinion, $\rvert z-2 \rvert=(z^*)^2-1$ is impossible

Is it correct?

Thanks!

Comment: $\sqrt{(a-2)^2}$ can either be $a-2$ or $2-a$, dependent on whether $a$ is greater or smaller than $2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got

$$\sqrt{(a-2)^2+b^2}=a^2-b^2-1-2abi$$

Comparing real and imaginary parts:

$$ab=0\implies a=0\;\;\text{or}\;\;b=0. \text{ In the first case we get:}\;\;$$

$$\sqrt{b^2+4}=-b^2-1\;<--\;\;\text{ impossible as left hand is non-negative always, so}$$

it must be

$$b=0\implies \sqrt{(a-2)^2}=a^2-1\implies a^2-4a+4=a^4-2a^2+1\implies$$

$$a^4-3a^2+4a-3=0$$

and we have two real roots:

$$a_{1,2}=\frac12\left(\pm\sqrt{13}-1\right)$$

and thus we have a solutions: $\;z=\frac12\left(\pm\sqrt{13}-1\right)\;$

Comment: Note that you can find these roots easily because your fourth degree polynomial is $(a^2-1)^2-(a-2)^2$ which factors as a difference of squares. This reduces to the two aces, $a^2-1=a-2$ and $a^2-1=2-a$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\;\bar z^2=1+\lvert z-2 \rvert \in \mathbb{R}^+\,$ so $\,\bar z = \pm \sqrt{1+\lvert z-2 \rvert} \in \mathbb{R}\,$, therefore $z = \bar z \in \mathbb{R}\,$. Then either:

- $\;z \lt 2\;$ and $\;-(z-2)=z^2-1\;$
- $\;z \ge 2\;$ and $\;z-2=z^2-1\;$